# rotation along a coordinate axis and Kac random walk

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

With due respect, I am profoundly puzzled by an amazing [paper](http://www.springerlink.com/index/1y9bkugfdldk6wek.pdf) of David K. Maslen on the eigenvalues of the Kac random walk on $SO(n)$. 
The Kac walk is essentially given by choosing a random pair of coordinates $i \neq j \in [n]$ and rotating by a uniformly random angle about the 2-plane $i \wedge j$.  In section 3.1, he defined an auxilliary random walk by "the following procedure of choosing random elements in $SO(n)$: first choose a random coordinate axis in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then choose a random angle $\theta$ uniformly in $[0,2\pi)$. then the rotation by $\theta$ about the chosen axis is the chosen random element of $SO(n)$."

To me a random rotation always occurs along a 2-dimensional plane. So I have no idea how to rotate along a coordinate axis.

He then went on to define the Fourier transform of this random rotation in an irreducible representation space. 
  " Let $P_{\hat{i}}$ be the self-adjoint projection from $V_\rho$ onto the subspace of $\sigma SO(n-1) \sigma^{-1}$-invariant vectors, where $\sigma$ is the transposition matrix for $(i,n)$. Then $\frac{1}{n}(P_{\hat{1}} + \ldots + P_{\hat{n}})$ is the Fourier transform of the measure we defined for a uniform random rotation in a random coordinate hyperplane. "
  If someone can make sense of the description of the random rotation defined in the first paragraph, please also enlighten me why the Fourier transform is of the above form. I assume he is talking about real representation here?

In particular, I see that if $\rho$ is the natural representation, then the Fourier transform would simply be $1/n$ times the identity matrix.

As a final remark, the Kac walk is not constant on conjugacy classes, hence standard representation theory isn't useful for its analysis. I must say that Maslen's paper contains such a rich amount of new discoveries about representation theory and semi-standard Young tableau stuff that I am eager to find out its connection with standard representation theory on compact simple Lie groups. Also if someone thinks he or she understands this paper quite thoroughly, please help me out by getting in touch with me.

Comment: Concerning your second paragraph: I too have no idea how to rotate *along* an axis, but the passage you quoted says to rotate *about* the chosen axis, and that makes perfectly good sense.

Comment: Hi Andreas, 
   Thanks for your comments. I still don't know how to "rotate about the chosen axis"? You know my English is not so good, so could you help me out once more?

Comment: Concerning your third paragraph: Presumably, $SO(n-1)$ is regarded as the subgroup of $SO(n)$ consisting of rotations fixing the $n$-th coordinate axis.  Then $\sigma SO(n-1)\sigma^{-1}$ is the subgroup of $SO(n)$ consisting of rotations fixing the $i$-th coordinate axis.  If you combine this observation with the fact that Maslen wrote about the projection (not to $\sigma SO(n-1)\sigma^{-1}$, which wouldn't make sense, but) to the subspace of $\sigma SO(n-1)\sigma^{-1}$-invariant vectors, things should make more sense.

Comment: You're right, rotation about an axis, in the usual sense, is reasonable in 3 dimensions.  In $n$ dimensions, the "axis" should consist of all but 2 coordinate directions, leaving a 2-dimensional plane in which to rotate.  I think Maslen wants a single coordinate axis, and therefore the random choice of $\theta$ should not be just an angle but a rotation in the complementary $n-1$-dimensional space.  That fits with what he wrote in the next paragraph about the Fourier transform.

Comment: Ah great. So $\theta$ is really a uniform element in $SO(n-1)$ I guess? I corrected the misquoted portion of my question. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Maslen's is a nice result, but I note that it has been cited only seven times (as per MathSciNet) so "famous" might be overstating the matter a little.

Comment: @Igor: I changed it to "amazing", which is a more ambiguous hence less controversial adjective.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.